# is it sneak peep or sneak peek

Tags: word-choice

Is it right to say *sneak peep* instead of *sneak peek*?

Meaning of *peep* in Google is:

> look quickly and furtively at something, especially through a narrow opening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **sneak peek**. Sneak *peep* is not even on the map.

Take a look:

[image]

Comment: `sneak peak` is widely used but it doesn't mean `sneak peep` is wrong. Right?

Comment: Personally, I've never heard or seen *sneak peep*. A Google search for it shows some usage, but you're way out on a limb here, considering the Ngram graph above. I think *sneak peep* is understandable, but evidently the rules of collocation typically require the word *peek*, not *peep* after *sneak*.

Comment: @EmptyData - Well no, "sneak peep" isn't *wrong*, it's just not common. Just as "a sneaky quick and furtive look through a narrow opening" isn't a particularly common phrase...

Answer (score 0):

Both *peek* and *peep* are defined similarly, but I would say that *peek* is the more commonly seen of the two.

Comment: You are talking about America. *Peep* is the older word, having existed at least since the 15th century and is more commonly used in Britain, especially with such expressions as *peeping Tom*. Indeed it may have been for *peep's* associations with sexual matters that the word *peek* was coined in puritan America. That was the case with a number of words and is believed to explain why they call a *cock* a *rooster*. But the term *sneak peek* is used in Britain - the effects of living in a global society, no doubt.

Comment: @WS2 - I haven't counted, but I reckon I hear [*"sneaky peek"*](http://www.birminghammail.co.uk/whats-on/music-nightlife-news/take-sneaky-peek-inside-new-9977972) at least as frequently.